# Python Code to get the html data of a table present in the source page

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and I am trying to scrape a website.
I am able to log in into a website and get a html page, but i dont need the whole page, i just need the hyperlink in the specified table.

I have written the below code, but this gets all the hyperlinks.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
for table in soup.findAll('table',{'id':'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1'} ):
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
                print link.get('href')
```

Can anyone help me where am i going wrong?

Below is the html text of the table

```
<table id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1" width="680px">
 <tr id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Tr1">
    <td id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Td1">
                        <table id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_itemPlaceholderContainer" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tr id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Tr2" style="background-color:#0090dd;">
            <th id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Th1"></th>
            <th id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Th2">

                                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_SortByAcctNum" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByAcctNum','')">
                                        <font color=white>
                                            <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_AcctNum">Account number</span>
                                        </font>

                                        </a>
                                </th>
            <th id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Th4">
                                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_SortByServAdd" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByServAdd','')">
                                    <font color=white>
                                        <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ServiceAddress">Service address</span>
                                    </font>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
            <th id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Th5">
                                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_SortByAcctName" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByAcctName','')">
                                    <font color=white>
                                        <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_AcctName">Name</span>
                                    </font>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
            <th id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Th6">
                                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_SortByStatus" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByStatus','')">
                                    <font color=white>
                                        <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_AcctStatus">Account status</span>
                                    </font>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
            <th id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Th3"></th>
        </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which hyperlink of those do you need?

Comment: all the href for all the a anchor tags, and i have pasted just a part of the html, list there are lot many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your for loop looks up in the table html (and not `soup` variable, which is the page html):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
table = page.find('table', {'id': 'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1'})
links = table.findAll('a')

# Print href
for link in links:
   link['href']
```

#### Result

```
In [8]: table = page.find('table', {'id' : 'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1'})

In [9]: links = table.findAll('a')

In [10]: for link in links:
   ....:     print link['href']
   ....:     
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByAcctNum','')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByServAdd','')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByAcctName','')
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$SortByStatus','')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\latest1.py", line 59, in <module>
    table = the_page.find('table', {'id': 'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1'})
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method -- getting this error

Comment: what version of python and beautifulsoup are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the right way to do it.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
for table in soup.findAll('table',{'id':'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1'} ): 
        for link in table.findAll('a'): #search for links only in the table
                print link['href'] #get the href attribute
```

Also, you can skip the parent loop, since there would be only one match for the specified id:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_Table1'})
for link in table.findAll('a'): #search for links only in the table
                print link['href'] #get the href attribute
```

Update: Noticed what @DSM said. Fixed a missing quote in the table assignment.

Comment: You're missing a `'` before `ctl`.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop `for link in soup.findAll('a'):` is searching the entire HTML page.
If you want to search for links within the table change that line to:

```
for link in table.findAll('a'):
```

Comment: Thanks it work. but still i need only few links only. Like now i am getting all the links 
but in these i need only select links and not the delete links. the html code for the selecl link is  <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl1_lnkSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl1$lnkSelect','')">View </a>